# 4.23 Lab countdown until matching digits in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

So i have this lab and i kept getting 9 out of ten correct. I ended up changing my original code to this very wacky version to accommodate the extra point. The question is:

Write a program that takes in an integer in the range 20-98 as input. The output is a countdown starting from the integer, and stopping when both output digits are identical.

my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userDigit;
      int newDigit;

      userDigit = scnr.nextInt();

      newDigit = userDigit - 1;

      if ((userDigit > 19) && (userDigit < 99)) {
         System.out.print(userDigit + " ");

      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Input must be 20-98");
      }


      while ((userDigit > 19) && (userDigit < 99) && (newDigit % 11 != 0)) {
         if (userDigit % 11 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
            break;
         }
         System.out.print(newDigit + " ");
         --newDigit;

         if (newDigit % 11 == 0) {
            System.out.println(newDigit + " ");
            break;
         }
      }


   }
}
```

Can someone please tell me if i over thought this and if there was an easier way to format the for loop without having all the "ifs". I am new at this and have been taking the class for 4 weeks now. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I know there was probably some way to use another method, but the instructions stated to use a "while" loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userDigit = scnr.nextInt();
    scnr.close();

    if ((userDigit <= 19) || (userDigit >= 99))
        System.out.println("Input must be 20-98");

    do {
        System.out.println(userDigit + " ");
        if (userDigit % 11 == 0)
            break;

        --userDigit;

    } while ((userDigit > 19));
}
```

Since the original value of `userDigit` would not need to be used again, the extra variable `newDigit` could be skipped.

In addition, if while-loop is required, then considering do-while could help to print the initial input at the first place, which could help to skip the subsequent redundant checking.

Afterwards, you could simply operate on the original `userDigit` ( check if current value could be divided by 11; **'yes'**: jump out of while-loop, **'no'**: decrement it, and keep repeating these steps)